# Cant archive ios app

Tags: ios, xcode

I tried to archive app for ios devise. But archivation failed.
Xcode show me: `Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain`

What happened? How to archive app for testing app on ios devise?

Comment: Do you have a valid Developer Account? Or a Developer University Account?
Have you added the Device to Portal? Check thin in te Organizer

Comment: i didnt know about Organizer. thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of XCode's rare error messages that is actually descriptive and precise. You can break the message down a bit and make a little more sense of it.

---

> The identity 'iPhone Developer' ...

This suggests that you are trying to use your developer profile to make an archive when you should be using your distribution certificate and provisioning profile.

Have a look at [this page](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action). (Apple login is required) if you don't have a distribution profile.

---

> ... doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain.

Even if you are using your distribution certificate (I don't think this is the case based on the first part of the message but if you are sure it is your distribution certificate and it's just badly named, please continue). Go to Keychain Access and check that your iPhone distribution certificates (and any other relevant certificates) haven't expired.

If it's neither of these, go to Organizer and check that your provisioning profiles haven't expired either.